# Is there a simple way to see which PCI device my NVME is?

Tags: linux, nvme

I have a U.2 SSD, which shows up as nvme1n1 in lsblk:

```
root@eris:~# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0  3.6T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  476M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 38.1G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  3.6T  0 part /data
nvme1n1     259:4    0  3.5T  0 disk
```

Looking in dmesg, I can see that:

```
root@eris:~# dmesg | grep -i nvme
[    0.997417] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:01:00.0
[    0.997448] nvme nvme1: pci function 0000:04:00.0
...
```

And this matches:

```
root@eris:~# ll /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme | grep 04:00.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  4 14:41 0000:04:00.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0
```

Which is something I will need to know for later.

My question is, is there a simpler way to get from `/dev/nvme1n1` to `/sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/0000:04:00.0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah,

```bash
ls -la /dev/disk/by-path

# or
cd /sys/block
for i in nvme*; do
    echo "$i is `cat $i/device/address`"
done
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thx!